# Cannot find module environment when running in server side with Angular Universal

Tags: node.js, angular, environment, angular-universal

I have a simple Angular 4 app that I want to run in server side with Angular Universal (nodeJs server side rendering).
I followed [these steps](https://coursetro.com/posts/code/68/Make-your-Angular-App-SEO-Friendly-(Angular-4-+-Universal)) to configure the Angular Universal with the angular-cli help and it's all good until I try to use the angular environment.
When I try to access a property within the environment constant it works perfectly being rendered in client side (with ng serve) but in server side (`ts-node src/server.ts`) it throws the following error:

```
Error: Cannot find module 'environments/environment'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:470:15)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:418:25)
    at Module.require (module.js:498:17)
    at require (internal/module.js:20:19)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Dev\code-carama\src\app\auth.service.ts:3:1)
    at Module._compile (module.js:571:32)
    at Module.m._compile (C:\Dev\code-carama\node_modules\ts-node\src\index.ts:385:23)
    at Module._extensions..js (module.js:580:10)
    at Object.require.extensions.(anonymous function) [as .ts] (C:\Dev\code-carama\node_modules\ts-node\src\index.ts:388:12)
    at Module.load (module.js:488:32)

npm ERR! Windows_NT 10.0.14393
npm ERR! argv "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "start"
npm ERR! node v7.10.0
npm ERR! npm  v4.2.0
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! code-carama@0.0.0 start: `ts-node src/server.ts`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the code-carama@0.0.0 start script 'ts-node src/server.ts'.
npm ERR! Make sure you have the latest version of node.js and npm installed.
npm ERR! If you do, this is most likely a problem with the code-carama package,
npm ERR! not with npm itself.
npm ERR! Tell the author that this fails on your system:
npm ERR!     ts-node src/server.ts
npm ERR! You can get information on how to open an issue for this project with:
npm ERR!     npm bugs code-carama
npm ERR! Or if that isn't available, you can get their info via:
npm ERR!     npm owner ls code-carama
npm ERR! There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\dima\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2017-06-05T12_00_03_595Z-debug.log
```

This is my `server.ts`:

```
import 'reflect-metadata';
import 'zone.js/dist/zone-node';
import { platformServer, renderModuleFactory } from '@angular/platform-server';
import { enableProdMode } from '@angular/core';
import { AppServerModuleNgFactory } from '../dist/ngfactory/src/app/app.server.module.ngfactory';
import * as express from 'express';
import { readFileSync } from 'fs';
import { join } from 'path';

const PORT = 4000;

enableProdMode();

const app = express();

let template = readFileSync(join(__dirname, '..', 'dist', 'index.html')).toString();

app.engine('html', (_, options, callback) => {
  const opts = { document: template, url: options.req.url };

  //it serves html from the compiled angular app from the server
  renderModuleFactory(AppServerModuleNgFactory, opts)
    .then(html => callback(null, html));
});

app.set('view engine', 'html');
app.set('views', 'src')

app.get('*.*', express.static(join(__dirname, '..', 'dist')));

app.get('*', (req, res) => {
  res.render('index', { req });
});

app.listen(PORT, () => {
  console.log(`listening on http://localhost:${PORT}!`);
});
```

And the simple service trying to access environment variables is the `auth.service.ts`:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { environment } from 'environments/environment';

@Injectable()
export class AuthService {

  private userManager = null;
  constructor() { 
    console.log('AuthService instantiated in environment ' + environment.envName); //this will fail in server-side rendering
  }
}
```

**Any idea what's going with nodeJs (or angular universal) not to find that environment module?**

Thanks

Answer (score 11):

In projects Angular6 change 'environments/environment' by 'src/environments/environment'

Comment: worked for me in Angular 7 (project migrated from Angular 6).  I'm new to Angular

Answer (score 9):

Never mind, it seems the problem is that although for client side rendering the line:

`import { environment } from 'environments/environment';`

works well, for server side rendering the line must be:

`import { environment } from '../environments/environment';`

and by the way, I don't know why but by default for server-side rendering it will pick the PROD environment file.

on console: `AuthService instantiated in environment prod`

Answer (score 5):

try to execute this commande `npm run env` and then execute `ng serve`. It's work with me

Answer (score 1):

**app.module.ts**

Add this line:

```
import { environment } from '../environments/environment';
```

Answer (score 1):

On Angular 15 the environment folder has been removed, but there is a solution released on version 15.1 to generate the folder:

```
ng generate environments
```

it will create `src/environments/environment.ts` and `src/environments/environment.development.ts` then inside your service or component import it as:

```
import { environment } from 'src/environments/environment';
```

and then you can use it like:

```
baseUrl: string = environment.baseUrl;
```

Answer (score 0):

In your `environment.ts` add the following:

```
 export const environment = {
    production: false
 };
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

You just need to find the location of your environment.ts file.

With angular 14:

If you have your ts file here:

src\app\auth\reducers\index.ts

The answer is:

```
import { environment } from '../../../environments/environment';
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you see environments folder in src folder?

And then, can you see environment.ts and environment.prod.ts on there?

If so, based on your depiction of the filesystem, you need to go back up one more level.

```
import { environment } from '../../environments/environment';
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all create environments directory. After that create `environment.ts` file with `firebaseConfig` (in my case).
The key is call with double (`../../`) this line:

```
import { environment } from '../../src/environments/environment';
```

Answer (score -1):

For me, some of build variants `dev` and `prod` were having some different const name

`export const AppConfig {`

instead of

`export const environment {`

Answer (score -1):

Check that you do not have it ignored in the .gitignore

Comment: What does .gitignore have to do with this?